# Drupal: Stay on same page after registration

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I have a block with the registration form in it, I need people to register and stay on that same exact page, is that possible?

I tried the login destination module but that feature only seem to work on the login not register. Register keep sending to user profile page.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [user_register_submit submit handler](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_submit/6), `$form_state['submit']` is hardcoded.

That means that user_register_submit will define the destination, unless you override it.

You can do that by adding your own submit handler (pseudo code).

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "user_register") {
    //Look at the code in user_register_submit for all the ifs and switches to only
    // add this extra handler when a normal user signs up.
    $form['#submit'][] = "_mymodule_user_register_submit";
  }
}

function _mymodule_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = $_GET['q']; //Adds the current url as redirect.
}
```

Then, using the weights in the system table, make sure your modulestarts after the user module. Otherwise they are called alphabetically, user module coming after mymodule; resetting the redirect again.

And never, ever, use `drupal_goto()` in submit handlers, because they will stop all processing and redirect the user, causing many modules to fail and often even causing broken and inconsistent databases.

Comment: never made a module before but I followed [this site](http://mrphp.com.au/code/how-make-simple-form-module-drupal) and got this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/dkdconce/public_html/forex/sites/all/modules/reg_form/reg_form.module on line 8

Comment: I added a warning about my code being pseudocode. And fixed an error, the one that caused your problem. a ; on line 5.

Comment: Also, when you have none-programming related Drupal-questsions, you are better off at drupal.stackexchange.com. This site is for programmers, mainly.

Comment: the error is gone now but, when I go to a page and create and from that page, it still redirects me to the user page. I also set the weight to -99. I went to drupal stackexchange, no help there.

Comment: $GET['q'] should be $_GET['q']